# Запятые украли.

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Теперь ещё один добропорядочный человек будет в полнолуние превращаться в молдаванина!

Столкнулся с таким комментарием в интернете.
Где в нем пропущены запятые?Я думал после слова "теперь" запятая не ставится...В таких ситуациях.

Comment: Никакие запятые в этом предложении, конечно, не нужны. Склонность подвергать все сомнению, несомненно, прекрасное качество. Но это вовсе не значит, что эту склонность нужно доводить до паранойи.

Comment: К этому комментарию написали другой комментарий,мол,у вас запятые украли;) А я долго не мог понять,где их украли.Расплодилось граммар-наци в интернете,которые сами писать не умеют и другим тыкают.

Comment: > К этому комментарию написали другой комментарий,мол,у вас запятые украли;) А я долго не мог понять,где их украли.Расплодилось граммар-наци в интернете,которые сами писать не умеют и другим тыкают.

Я догадалась)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно, запятая после "теперь" здесь не нужна. Это обычный член предложения.